# ERROR: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 10000ms

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, rest, hikaricp

I am developing an API... and after requested several endpoints the server show me this message...

```
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null Jun 24, 2016 9:51:45 PM
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions ERROR: 
HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 10000ms. Jun
24, 2016 9:51:45 PM com.healthymama.utils.DEVLoggingFilter log INFO: 967 * 
Server responded with a response on thread grizzly-http-server-2
```

The project is made with hibernate, mysql and Hikari... Could you help me? Thanks!

Here the configuration:

```
 url = String.format("jdbc:mysql://%s:%s/%s?autoReconnect=true", host, port, bundle.getString("db.database"));

 configuration
                .setProperty("hibernate.order_updates", "true")
                .setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect")
                .setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update")
                .setProperty("hibernate.connection.provider_class", "com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider")
                .setProperty("hibernate.hikari.dataSourceClassName", "com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource")
                .setProperty("hibernate.hikari.dataSource.url", url)
                .setProperty("hibernate.hikari.dataSource.user", username)
                .setProperty("hibernate.hikari.dataSource.password", password)
                .setProperty("hibernate.hikari.dataSource.cachePrepStmts", "true")
                .setProperty("hibernate.hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize", "250")
                .setProperty("hibernate.hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048")
                .setProperty("hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle", "5")
                .setProperty("hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle", "5")
                .setProperty("hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize", "10")
                .setProperty("hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout", "30000")
                .setProperty("hibernate.hikari.connectionTestQuery", "SELECT 1")
                .setProperty("hibernate.hikari.connectionTimeout", "10000");
```